# Laravel : cannot run artisan config:cache

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded my local laravel files to a live hosting and updated my .env file

**local .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wf_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**live .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=live_db
DB_USERNAME=live_username
DB_PASSWORD=live_password
```

when I run `php artisan config:cache` it throws this error.

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have updated the `config/database.php` file as well and run `config:cache` again but still I get the same error.

I'm pretty sure my live hosting configs are correct as I have other laravel projects in that hosting server.

Comment: Make sure your local env file is not in the live server anywhere, and that you're actually testing against the correct machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that you're modifying the correct .env.
- If you can't run config:cache to apply your .env changes, you can drop the cached files manually, stored in bootstrap/cache.

Comment: I deleted the cached files manually and it worked! Thank you so much!